# grep or awk or sed to concatenate or merge two files linux

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a file1.csv file which has four columns.

```
udp,4080,10.11.76.172,10.121.147.99
tcp,22,10.21.146.131,10.131.149.91
tcp,8080,10.56.10.91,10.151.150.90
```

Another file2.yml file as below

```
ssh_port: "22"
Jenkins_port: 8080
sqlstr_port: "5162-5164"
```

I need to compare the two files and merge to one based on the port number.

I have tried something like this.

```
for port in $(cat file1.csv | cut -d',' -f2); do if [[ $port =~ ..
```

Is there any simple method where I can merge two files based on the port number, Where I need to get the output similar to like this.

```
tcp,22,10.21.146.131,10.131.149.91,ssh_port
tcp,8080,10.56.10.91,10.151.150.90,jenkins_port
```

Comment: Use `awk`: Read `file2.yml` into an array. Then read `file1.csv` and find the array element that corresponds to the port number.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you(this will not consider that your values have port ranges in file2).

```
awk 'FNR==NR{sub(/:/,"",$1);gsub(/\"/,"",$NF);a[$NF]=$1;next} ($2 in a){print $0,a[$2]}' FIle2.yml  FS="," OFS="," FIle1.csv
```

***EDIT:*** If you have ranges in your file2 separated with `-` then following may help you on same too.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{sub(/:/,"",$1);gsub(/\"/,"",$NF);if($NF~/-/){num=split($NF,array,"-");for(i=array[1];i<=array[num];i++){a[i]=$1}} else {a[$NF]=$1};next} ($2 in a){print $0,a[$2]}' FIle2.yml  FS="," OFS="," FIle1.csv
```

Adding a non-one liner form of above solution too now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  sub(/:/,"",$1);
  gsub(/\"/,"",$NF);
  if($NF~/-/)                          { num=split($NF,array,"-");
    for(i=array[1];i<=array[num];i++)  { a[i]=$1 }}
  else                                 {a[$NF]=$1}; next }
    ($2 in a)                          { print $0,a[$2]  }
' FIle2.yml  FS="," OFS="," FIle1.csv
```

Comment: Thanks RavinderSingh, The first solution worked for me even with the ranges. I'm having trouble executing the second one though. It is taking forever for the execution. Am I missing something?

Comment: @andy, it worked for me fine when I tested it, could you please use `set -x` before this command or put `set -x` and `awk` command in a `.ksh` script and let me know what it shows you?

Answer (score 2):

Extended **`awk`** solution considering multiple ports like `5162-5164`:

```
awk 'NR == FNR{ 
         gsub(/[:"]/, ""); 
         len = split($2, a, "-"); 
         for (i=1; i<=len; i++) ports[a[i]] = $1;
         next 
     }
     $2 in ports{ print $0, ports[$2] }' file2.yml FS=',' OFS=',' file1.csv
```

The output:

```
tcp,22,10.21.146.131,10.131.149.91,ssh_port
tcp,8080,10.56.10.91,10.151.150.90,Jenkins_port
```